# Pretty JSON/JSON Tree View in flutter Devtools

Tags: flutter, flutter-devtools

Is there a way to pretty print json or view with tree view so that i can view the json tree in a structured manner and not be a huge string dump?(like in chrome)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [json_view](https://pub.dev/packages/json_view) to achieve this behavior

[image]

Comment: this is on the flutter devtools and not flutter app itself